# How to show form error on failed login

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm using ajax to submit core's `user_login_block` which is displayed in a popup. I'm using `ajax_command_replace` to show the error message if login fails. (If login is successful, I reload the page.) For some reason, it doesn't run and the error message doesn't show. Any reason why? Or is there a better way to show the errors via ajax response?

In my hook_form_alter

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="form-login-popup">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_theme_login_block_submit';
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
  'wrapper' => 'form-login-popup',
  'callback' => 'user_login_submit',
);
```

And in my_theme_login_block_submit

```
$commands = array();

$messages = drupal_get_messages(NULL, FALSE);

if(!count($messages) || !isset($messages['error']) || !count($messages['error'])) {
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');
  $commands[] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
  print ajax_render($commands);
  drupal_exit();
}

$commands[] = ajax_command_replace(NULL, theme('status_messages') .   render($form));
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```